# Adding a Header line to a Git ".md" file

Tags: git, header, markdown

I want to add a line to a created ".md" file using markdown in Git. How can I do that and how can I check whether it is typed and add to document correctly?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want? Do you want this automatically, if so: what content, when should this happen?

Comment: I've already made a ".md" file Using Git Bash ... by using this syntax "touch test-file"... Now I want to add a line "This is my first line" in this file... How can I add that? and how can I check the output ? (I mean how can I open that and see my line )

Comment: It's just a text file. You can edit it using any text editor, although you won't see the styled version unless you use some tool that understands markdown.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Thanks Matt ! Can I also add a line to the new text by using Git Bash? if "yes"  how?

Comment: Well, you could do something like `echo "Add this content" > yourfile.md` but a text editor will be easier in most cases.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! really appreciate that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown files are really just text files. Pretty much anything can open them.

If you're using Git, chances are you have some kind of code-editor. Try this first. It will probably open the file alright. It might even provide helpful things like a preview or syntax-highlighting

If you don't have a code-editor and are on Windows try "notepad" or "wordpad".
If you're on Linux, try gedit, gvim, or on any terminal try nano, vim.

Comment: Thanks so much  !! I checked that with "notepad" ... Can you just tell me is it possible to add a line in that file by using Git Bash or not ? and if "yes" how ?

Comment: if you just need to add some text, you could type this on the git bash (or also in a shell script): `echo "test 1234" >> file.md`. The `>>` mean "append to a file", instead of echo, you could also use any output of any other command like `ls` or `git status`

Answer (score 0):

The format is called Markdown. You can use an editor to help you format your Markdown documents. There are even in-browser editors, like http://dillinger.io/